# Need Help Writing (a Pascal) Matrix in Mathematica

Tags: combinatorics, matrix

I want to write a function $f[n]$ in Mathematica which gives me an $n\times n$ lower triangular Pascal matrix with a row of zeros in between each nonzero row. That is, I want the matrices
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&2&1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&2&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&3&3&1&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: luis, I updated my answer.  Hopefully it is now easier to understand and more practical.

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100290) is a related thread.

Answer (score 5):

Simplistically you could use `Binomial` and `Array`, and then interleave zero rows.  (See the edit history of this post for an example.)  A better method is to craft a function using `Binomial` that returns the right value directly, which would be useful if you don't want to generate the entire array at once.  The function below indexes from zero, which is unusual in *Mathematica* but aligns with `Binomial`.

```
f1 = If[OddQ @ #, 0, Binomial[#/2, #2]] &;
```

A 7 x 7 matrix:

```
Array[f1, {7, 7}, 0] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For large matrices you will find that other methods to generate the underlying triangle are faster:

```
f2[n_] :=
  With[{pt = NestList[{0, ##} + {##, 0} & @@ # &, {1}, n - 1]},
    ArrayFlatten @ 
      Riffle[{{PadRight[pt, {n, 2 n - 1}]}} ~Transpose~ {3, 2, 1}, {{0}}]
  ]
```

This function builds the full array to a specified degree:

```
f2[4] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is significantly faster than the first function:

```
Array[f1, {1500, 1500}, 0]; // Timing // First

f2[1500]; // Timing // First
```

> 2.668
>
> 0.687

There are going to be faster methods using the symmetry of the triangle and compilation but I will not elaborate unless asked, as the question does not mention performance.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can use `SparseArray[]` to generate your padded Pascal matrix:

```
With[{n = 7}, 
     SparseArray[{j_, k_} /; OddQ[j] && j >= k :> 
                 Binomial[Quotient[j, 2], k - 1], {n, n}] // Normal]
   {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way :

```
f[n_?IntegerQ] := Riffle[PadRight[#, 2 n + 1] & /@ 
   Outer[Binomial[#1, #2] &, Range[0, n], Range[0, n]], 
     {ConstantArray[0, 2 n + 1]}]

f[2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: mat2]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
makeArray[nu_] :=
 Riffle[
  PadRight[#, 2*nu - 1] & /@ Table[
    Binomial[n, k],
    {n, 0, nu - 1},
    {k, 0, n}
    ],
  ConstantArray[0, {1, 2*nu - 1}]
  ]

makeArray[4] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `` LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix `` function provided by Mathematica.

For example:

```
LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix[6]//CholeskyDecomposition//Transpose//MatrixForm
```

gives

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

To obtain the answer to your question:

```
MatrixForm[Most[Transpose[CholeskyDecomposition[LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix[6]]]/.a:{_Integer..}:>Sequence[Join[a,ConstantArray[0,Length[a]-1]],ConstantArray[0,2Length[a]-1]]]]
```

yields

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Can you expand on this answer, maybe with code to demonstrate your claim?