# Create a Pascal Matrix

Tags: matrix

I am trying to write a function that can create a [Pascal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix). So far I have

```
P[m_, n_] := Table[(#1!/(#2! (#1 - #2)!)) & /@ Thread[i + j - 1, i - 1],
                   {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}] // MatrixForm
```

but this doesn't give me the right matrix and I am not sure what is wrong.

Can someone tell me where the error is? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A much simpler solution:

```
P[m_, n_] := MatrixForm@Table[Binomial[i + j-2, i-1], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];
```

or something closer to your attempt:

```
P[m_, n_] :=  Table[Apply[(#1!/(#2! (#1 - #2)!)) &, {i + j - 2, i - 1}], 
   {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Can you tell what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Simple You used `Thread` wrong. You might have confused `Thread`with `Apply`? You also need to use `i+j-2`. I'll add a solution that's closer to your style.

Answer (score 12):

Oh poor Stephen Wolfram.. no one honors his life's work by giving an answer that uses a cellular automaton. Let me fix this. Here a version for square matrices

```
P[n_] := #.Transpose[#] &@
  CellularAutomaton[{{i_, j_} :> i + j}, {{1}, 0}, n - 1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And for rectangular arrays, just truncate the above solution

```
P[n_, m_] := P[Max[n, m]][[;; n, ;; m]]
```

Comment: I have a solution using Feynman diagrams too, but seems off topic :)

Answer (score 6):

From [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix)

```
l[n_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} -> Binomial[i - 1, j - 1], n]
u[n_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} -> Binomial[j - 1, i - 1], n]
s[n_] := l[n].u[n]

l[7] // MatrixForm
u[7] // MatrixForm
s[7] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or equivalently:

```
l[n_] := MatrixExp@SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> Range[n - 1], n]
u[n_] := MatrixExp@SparseArray[Band[{1, -n + 1}] -> Range[n - 1], n]
s[n_] := l[n].u[n]

l[7] // MatrixForm
u[7] // MatrixForm
s[7] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Alternatively: `Array[1/((#1 + #2 - 1) Beta[#1, #2]) &, {7, 7}]`. Then the triangles can be extracted via `CholeskyDecomposition[]`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nicely compact solution, whose proof is left to the interested reader:

```
pascal[n_Integer?Positive] := NestList[Accumulate, ConstantArray[1, n], n - 1]
```

It's surprisingly quick:

```
With[{n = 50},
     AbsoluteTiming[Array[Binomial[#1 + #2, #1] &, {n, n}, {0, 0}];]]
   {0.054873, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[pascal[50];]
   {0.001829, Null}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `` LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix ``.

Example:

```
In[57]:= LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix[3]

Out[57]= {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 6}}
```

It is very quick too:

```
In[65]:= AbsoluteTiming[LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix[50];]

Out[65]= {0.000190, Null}
```

It has one option:

```
In[86]:= Options[LinearAlgebra`PascalMatrix]

Out[86]= {WorkingPrecision -> ∞}
```